# C# Identity cookie causing network related issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a login cookie for when users login, and it lasts for 5 hours. The cookie upon which user logs in and it's logic are like following:

```
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/User/Login"),
                CookieName = "_zlc901285",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromHours(5),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            app.UseWebApi(config);
            MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
        }
```

Now when the user logs in I add the cookie and authenticate the user like following:

```
public ActionResult Login(string password)
{
var user = GetUser.GetUserFromDatabase();
if(user.Password==password)
{
 // Now here adding the cookie
 var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
 identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, User.UserId.ToString()));
var claims = new List<Claim>();
var roles = User.UserRoles.ToList();
foreach (UserRoles role in roles)
{
 claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Roles.RoleName));
}
}
}
```

Once this cookie expires, and goes past 5 hours mark (it expires)... The users start receiving timeouts on my website and I managed to catch the exception which turned out to be this long exception that I cannot fully understand what is causing it:

```
Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.) StackTrace: 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)  
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)  
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)  
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)  
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)  
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)  
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)  
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()  
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)  
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()  
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()  
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)  
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)  
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)  
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)  
   at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()  
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)  
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()  
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()  
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues)  
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues)  
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SecurityStampValidator.<>c__DisplayClass2`3.<<OnValidateIdentity>b__1>d__4.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__2.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)  
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)  
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) // Date: 3/20/2019 7:29:50 AM // Inner exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've spent days and days trying to figure out what is happening, but no luck whatsoever..

Can someone help me out with this one, I'm clueless as to what is happening ? :(

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: If the authentication cookie has expired, the user should then be logged out, correct? What process is trying to access the database?  I see reference to sql server express local database in the error, is this error coming from your development environment or is this from a production environment?  When your authentication times out, are you then redirecting to the login page?

Comment: @Nicolay 

1st reply: That's correct - once the cookie expires - user indeed does gets redirected to the login page. Tested on development environment - works

2nd question reply: for the process I'm not sure, any process/call against the DB should be terminated once the user logs put (Is there any way I can check it?)

3rd reply: Yes from production environment sadly :(

4th reply: again yes once the cookie expires

Comment: In your dev environment, I would change your timeout to something short, like 5 mins, and let it sit. Then let the debugger show you where the issue is.  Some process is trying to interact with some database.

Comment: @Nicolay can you confirm if the  cookie setup is correct? =D At least that I can be sure of that so I can look into other issuses